# PHP Force Dynamic content into the DOM

Tags: php, javascript, dom

I'm trying to come up with a way to get the all HTML/text that a user sees on any given URL, even though much of what they see may be produced dynamically (on page-load, for example) that is not in the DOM, then manually loading the javascripts and putting the resulting data back into the page.

My thinking is this:

1. (naively) return array of all javascript files by scraping all the `<script>` tags src attribute.
2. return array of all on-page hard-coded javascripts like: `<script> var example = true; </script>`
3. create a function to decide the real URLs encountered in the internal and external page javascripts. For example, when encountering for example `$.ajax({ url: '/relative-js-file.js'`, it would figure out the absolute URL so PHP may access that page.
4. using PHP, load all of the javascript that was found on the page in a way that resembles it being loaded on the actual page itself (the page it came from).
5. take whatever data the javascript returns (plain, html, etc.), and inject this new plain-text and/or HTML back into the original page `<body>`.

I do realize this will not work a lot of the time, but my hope is that it would at least be a good starting point until I can find a better solution or create a more advanced function to handle unrecognizable/inaccessable javascript. For examlpe, the javascript itself preventing it from being loaded on any page other than its own.

**My Question**

Do you think this is a good approach to getting dynamic content that is not in the DOM, and forcing it in the DOM? Or can you think of a better approach? I appreciate your feedback and thoughts.

Comment: so you're trying to execute all that scraped javascript so you can pretend you were running this in a regular browser to begin with? you'd be better off using a headless browser and extracting the dom from that instead of building your own JS interpreter/execution engine.

Comment: I think what OP is trying to do is get all external resources and put them in a page so you end up with one large page instead of a small page referencing several js scripts. So like get the url from a `<script src='whatever.js'>` and putting the file inline in a script tag. Not necessarily parse the javascript in php.

Comment: @MarcB Yes, that's exactly what I am trying to do! Please put it in a question form so I can accept it as the answer, thanks!